# Обработчик кнопки назад

Tags: android, kotlin

Проблема в следующем:
у меня есть фрагмент, при нажатии кнопки назад меня перекидывает в  main программы, что меня устраивает, но если я вешаю в onCreate - addOnBackPressedCallback, в котором при некотором условии происходит действие, то дефолтное перемещение в main программы не работает

Вот метод, если кратко - если меню открыто, то закрыть его.

```
    private fun onBackPressed() {
   
        if (условие) {
            действие
        } 
    }
```

Далее вешаю его в onCreate

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  
       addOnBackPressedCallback { 
          onBackPressed() 
       }
   }
```

Если меню закрыто, то вызвать дефолтное поведение при нажатии кнопки назад

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вчём смысл вызывать его в onCreate? Просто через @Override перегрузи onBackPressed и в нём делай

```java
if(menu.isOpen()){
  //Если открыто
} 
Проверки на закрытость не надо но не забудь вызвать super
```

Comment: во фрагменте нельзя переопределить onBackPassed и соответственно сделать super

Comment: А, не заметил, а ё ты просто не юзаешь NavigationUI?

Comment: Никогда не юзал еще, но похоже придется)

Comment: Рекомендую, сам год избегал, но за 4 дня сделал старую прогу гораздо лучше и в Single Activity стиле. Не пожалел что потратил время на освоение, в добавок прихвати SafeArgs

Comment: К сожалению не получится, У меня снизу есть навигационная панель, если отерыт 1 фрагмент, нажата 1 кнопка нав. панели, если открыт 2 фрагмент то нажата 2 кнопка и тд. [Если я юзаю навигацию, то меняются только фрагменты, а кнопки то не переключаются

Comment: Эээм, ты явно что то не дочитал или не увидил, ибо NavigationUI в первую очередь разрабатывали под Drawer и BottomNav